# Editable grid in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid, grid

I was looking for a code of ASP.net editable grid view.
In some of website I got the coding. But it had a extra button like edit or update. On clicking to that button the grid becomes editable. You can see it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0).
But I want the grid to get edit when I click on the cell of a grid. I don't want extra button for clicking and then to edit. 
So how can make grid editable just on clicking on that?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use `RowDataBound` event of your `GridView` to achieve this. I have written a  sample of how you can do it. Alter it to your requirements.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" onrowdatabound="gv_RowDataBound" 
              onrowediting="gv_RowEditing">
</asp:GridView>
```

> Codebehind will look like this:

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
    gv.DataSource = YourDataSource;
    gv.DataBind();
}

protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gv, "Edit$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

    }
}

protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    this.LoadGrid();  
}
```